# Recent goodness-of-fit tests related to proper scoring rules, CRPS and work of Gneiting

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references, goodness-of-fit

In a conference, I overheard a casual discussion about testing goodness of fit (GOF). Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Cramer-von Mises and Anderson-Darling were mentioned as some established GOF tests, but then one researcher said that some new, higher-power tests have recently been developed. He could not recall any titles, but he mentioned Tilmann Gneiting, proper scoring rules and continuously ranked probability scores (CRPSs). These are the keywords I used when trying to look up these new tests myself. After some effort, I have found nothing, so I am turning for help here. Is anyone aware of such new GOF tests?

Comment: Maybe the researcher meant the recent paper here? https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-statistics-032921-020240

Tilmann Gneiting has always been working on forecasting - he and his coworkers draw the connection to model diagnostics in that paper

Comment: @Ute, at the first glance I do not see that they would be proposing an alternative to the established GOF tests mentioned in my post, but perhaps I need to dig deeper.

Comment: I did not see any GOF test there, either. Maybe the researcher did take it a bit broadly, or has heard Tilmann talking about unpublished research?

Comment: @Ute, this is not *that* recent. The new tests are supposedly already in use by academic financial economists, so I think they must have been published some 2-10 years ago. And they do not have to be by Gneiting himself, they could be extensions of his work.

Comment: Ah, this explains it, thanks :-)